# Why can I still go back to previous page after having logged out?

Tags: php, session

After I log out, why can I still go back to the previous web page? I already put:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    session_destroy();
?>
```

Comment: Please post a more complete question with some code samples.  There is no way we can help you with this without some information about your script

Comment: When you go back in your history, page isn't reloaded, but taken from cache. After refreshing site using F5 or Ctrl/Cmd+R, page is reloaded and you are logged out.

Comment: I already reloaded the page but still can go back to the secure page...my situation "After user success log in,user can view all the content and after user click link to logout,,user go to login page but the problem after log out  user can go back to the previous page,He supposedly log in first,,,

Comment: If you keep whether someone is 'logged in' in the database along with a 'last action id' and the state and time. Then once they are logged out and it is recorded. If they send anything prior to the latest 'state' and 'time' then it is a 'fail'. Of course they can always login again. This gives you chance to validate them again.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone is saying we need more info to help. But my guess is the session is not getting destroyed cause you already sent a header before that. Turn the *display_errors* on in your php.ini and set error_reporting to E_ALL. You'll get more info on what's happening.